# area in google map... defining points of a conve area

Tags: php, google-maps

my question is middle way between math and programming:

I have a collection of points defined by latitude and longitude.

I have to define which ones among those describe the biggest convex form and then give them to google map in the right order to define an area that is as said the biggest convex area we can have with the given points...

for the code i'm fine... i guess:

```
nazionearea = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: nazione,
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillOpacity: 0 
}); 
nazionearea.setMap(map);
```

Where nazione is an array with all coordinates. It's not that easy... any ideas?

I'd like to post an image but as a newbie is forbidden.

---

we found: quickHull
but still not working... 
is in php (exactly what i need)

```
include( 'convex_hull.php' );

$q="SELECT `long`, lat FROM geo_punti "; 
$query=mysql_query($q); 
echo mysql_error();      
while($point=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
{ $points[] = $point; } 

$hull = new ConvexHull($points); 
$punti = $hull->getHullPoints();
```

but i provide 10 points and i just get 2 as a risult

Comment: Upload the pic to one of the hosting sites like http://tinypic.com/ and post a link in your question.

Comment: The algorithm you need is this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0109/algorithm_0109.htm

Comment: thanks... i found something in php as i need called quickhull but still is not working...     http://westhoffswelt.de/blog/0040_quickhull_introduction_and_php_implementation.html/    i provide long and lat of all points to de script: `$q="SELECT `long`, `lat`  FROM geo_punti ";
  $query=mysql_query($q);
  echo mysql_error();
  while($point=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
  { $points[] = $point; } $hull = new ConvexHull($points);
  $punti = $hull->getHullPoints();`     but i provide 10 points but just 2 as a risult...